# How to generate a random character that is either a number or an alphabetic letter in pseudo-code

Tags: algorithm

As title says I am trying to generate a random character that has to be either a number or an alphabetic letter and I can't come up with an efficient way to do it.

Edit: Since I am using pseudo-code (and it's handwritten) making a string/array out of all possible values may not be a very good choice.

I was thinking about generating a random integer that matches the ascii code of letters and digits but I could not find a proper way to do it since they're not consecutive.

Comment: Best to post your inefficient approach to demo your starting point.  Do your need a highly balanced result (equal probability) or something simple?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica It doesn't have to have an equal probability I will probably just use the method "iamoren" stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is creating an array with all possible values, then randomly choosing one.
I'm going to assume that you meant "digit" when you wrote "number".
Also, that you want a letter regardless of capital or lowercase (I've used uppercase).

Here's a javascript code for it:

```js
var options="0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
console.log(options.charAt(Math.floor(options.length*Math.random())));
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about generating a random integer between 25 - 0 or 9 - 0 then adding either 97 or 48 to it to get the ascii code of the character. Is there any proper way to do it?

Comment: @Wolvington you could generate a random number from 0-35 and add 48 to it if it's less than 10, else add 87.  But choosing from an array is more robust and less prone to error.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use [`Number.prototype.toString(36)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString):

```js
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 36).toString(36));
```

This will produce a random number or lowercase letter.